# Forex coding in R, while loop issues inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, forex

I have some code

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(subset(Ident, coredata.Ident. == "Bull.Engulfing")$Date, format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
for(i in seq_along(dates)){

EnterPrice<-as.vector(Sept17$Open[(dates)])
StopLoss<-as.vector(EnterPrice-0.0050)
TakeProfit<-as.vector(EnterPrice+0.0100)
MinDate<-as.vector(Sept17$Low[(dates)])
MaxDate<-as.vector(Sept17$High[(dates)])
n<-0
m<-0
while (MinDate > StopLoss) {
  n<-n+1
  MinDate<-Sept17$Low[Sept17[dates,which.i=TRUE]+n]
}
while (MaxDate < TakeProfit) {
  m<-m+1
  MaxDate<-Sept17$High[Sept17[dates,which.i=TRUE]+m]
}
if (m<n) {
  F$Outcome=print("Win")
  F$Hours=m
} else {
  F$Outcome=print("Lose")
  F$Hours=n
}
}
```

This returns an error of

```
Error in `[.xts`(Sept17$High, Sept17[dates, which.i = TRUE] + m) : 
  subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Basically what it does is it takes some data called `Ident` and computes dates and times for when the `Ident` data says `Bull.Engulfing`. It then computes `EnterPrice, StopLoss, TakeProfit, MinDate` and `MaxDate` on each of the dates computed.

For each date/hour I want it to go through the `while` loop and work out how many hours (`n`) it takes for one of the conditions to not be satisfied in the while loop. I would like it to display a vector of either `Loss` if the `StopLoss` condition is not satisfied or `Profit` if the `TakeProfit` condition is not satisfied and I would like to display the number of hours (`n`) it takes to achieve the unsatisfied condition.

I have tried above but not sure where to go from there.

So for example, let's say a component of `dates` is `2017-01-01 10:00`.

The `EnterPrice` might be `1.3100` therefore the `StopLoss` would be `1.3050` and `TakeProfit` would be `1.3200`.

It would then check every hour after that using the `Sept17` data and if the min on that day and hour went less than the `StopLoss` it would say `Lose` in a vector, if the max on a day and hour went above the `TakeProfit` it would say `Win`, and it would tell me the number of hours (`n`) it would take to get there.

It would then loop through for every other date where a `Bull.Engulfing` occurred.

TIA

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Have updated code also. I now get the error above, not sure whether I need vectorized `for` loop?